# Unable to select radio button using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I want to select a radio button using selenium web driver. My code is

```
<div class="radio-switch-group" aria-label="RequestForCheckBox" role="menu">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="request_for" value="self" ng-model="data.form.requestFor" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <span class="radio-label" translate=""><span class="ng-scope">Self</span></span>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="request_for" value="other" data-ng-click="$scope.getDataHandler()" ng-model="data.form.requestFor" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <span class="radio-label" translate=""><span class="ng-scope">Others</span></span>
</label>
</div>
```

I tried to locate the element with code shown below

```
WebElement other = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"make-request-form\"]/div/section/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/label[2]/input")));
other.click();
```

But getting below

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id="make-request-form"]/div/section/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/label[2]/input (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'AUUR01VP1341', ip: '10.97.2.56', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\L100455\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 61.0.3163.100, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 9d15042c1c2c4eda197796e5fdf42243
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
    at auto.Automation.main(Automation.java:44)
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Which radio button are you trying to locate and click **Self** or **Others**?

Comment: I am trying to locate **Others**

Answer (score 1):

According to the thrown exception, you are running in the wait timeout.

Either your object is not existing after the default timeout of 20 seconds or the xPath you are using is wrong. You can try to use the following xPath to select the second label: `(//input[@name="request_for"])[2]`

Tipp: for a quick test, past your HTML code into a xPath generator (e.g.: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and test the xPath expression without the need to rerun Selenium.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still I am not able to locate the element

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your code trials moving ahead as you will be clicking one of the *Radio Buttons* instead of *ExpectedConditions* `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use **`elementToBeClickable()`** as follows :

- To click on the *Radio Button* associated with the text **Self** you can use the following line of code :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid' and @value='self']"))).click();
  ```
- To click on the *Radio Button* associated with the text **Others** you can use the following line of code :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid' and @value='other']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still I am not able to locate the element.

Comment: @rishabh `not able to locate` doesn't throws any light whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code trials and error stack trace for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()`